# ordering indexes by array values

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of integers and I want some code to produce an array for me with these specifications:

- first item is the index of the maximum of integer values
- second item is the index of highest value which is less than max
- the last item is the index of the minimum of integer values.

Assume

```
int totalvalue[] = {100, 120, 90, 110}
```

and I want this

> {1, 3, 0, 2}

Comment: This looks exactly like the question that was closed a few minutes ago.

Comment: You need a sorting algorythm. You could first sort the array and then find the value in totalvalue[] and print out the index.

Comment: "Please do my homework for me." Perhaps you might learn more by doing it yourself.

Comment: @user3284107 but remember that if the array has dups, he still have to keep track of the indexes.

Comment: How do you think this could be solved? Can you think of some pseudocode?

Comment: @mehdi, basically what you need is to keep a structure with values and their indexes and write your own sorting algorithm (there are many) but using this indirection level.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer totalvalue[] = { 100, 120, 90, 110 };

        List<Integer> original = Arrays.asList(totalvalue);

        List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(original);

        Collections.sort(copy, new Comparator<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Integer intger1, Integer intger2) {

                return intger2.compareTo(intger1);
            }
        });

        int[] finalArray = new int[totalvalue.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalvalue.length; i++) {
            finalArray[i] = original.indexOf(copy.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray));
    }
```

Comment: hhehehe,I wrote it in a textpad.let me change that to finalArray..Dont mind the semantics

Answer (score -1):

I'll borrow someone else's code that was recently deleted from here ;-)

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int array[] = { 90, 100, 90, 110 };

        Map<Integer, Integer> valueIndexMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int index = 0;
        for (int entry : array)
            valueIndexMap.put(entry, index++);

        //perform your sorting algorithm here on valueIndexMap.key

        Integer[] newArray = new Integer[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = valueIndexMap.get(array[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(newArray));
    }
```

there are some here https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html

and it's important to study them because they're the foundation of CS

good luck

Comment: And how is this better than the recently deleted code? It does not work for non-unique values in the array.

Comment: well, it's better than using Arrays.sort() in the wrong way, as it originally was doing :-) at least, this answer focus on the real issue (dealing with indirection) without providing an all-inclusive answer that does the homework